# match all parentheses between two curly brackets

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to find a RegEx pattern that lets me match on all parentheses (and their content) as long as these parentheses are between `{` and `}`.

Examples:

- `{foo (i,j) bar}` should match on `(i,j)`
- `{(i,j) foo (k,l) bar (m,n,o)}` should match on `(i,j)`, `(k,l)`, and `(m,n,o)`.
- `foo (i,j) bar` should not match on anything because the string is not between swirly brackets.
- `{foo (i,j) bar} (k,l)` should match on `(i,j)` but not `(k,l)` because the latter is outside of the swirly brackets.

The closest I came was with this pattern: `(?<=\{)[^\(].*\(.*?\).*(?=\})`. This pattern matched on the first, second, and fourth example, but matched on all of the content between the swirly brackets instead of only the parentheses and their content.

Comment: Are you coding this solution in PHP, C#, JavaScript, Java, Ruby...?

Comment: Ultimately, I will be using this in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```r
(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^{}]*?\K\([^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2oA4DT/1). If you want to make absolutely sure there is a closing `}` on the right, add a `(?=[^{}]*})` positive lookahead at the end:

```r
(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^{}]*?\K\([^()]*\)(?=[^{}]*})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2oA4DT/2).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|{)` - either end of the previous successful match or a `{` char
- `[^{}]*?` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the current overall match memory buffer
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?=[^{}]*})` - immediately on the right, there must be zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`.

See an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/pDKm8k):

```r
x <- "{(i,j) foo (k,l) bar (m,n,o)} should match on (h,j), (a,s), and (i,o,g)."
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?:\\G(?!\\A)|{)[^{}]*?\\K\\([^()]*\\)(?=[^{}]*})", x, perl=TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "(i,j)"   "(k,l)"   "(m,n,o)"
```

Comment: You have no idea how long I've tried solving this. _Thank you_, Wiktor, it worked beautifully!

Comment: @Christian Just added the R code with a base R solution. Note you won't be able to achieve this with stringr using the current pattern, you will need to remove `\K`, capture the parentheses matching pattern and use `stringr::str_match_all`. And if you need to match nested parentheses, you will only be able to do that with the base R solution with a bit of a modification, let me know if it is needed.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. 
Two comments for others in case it is useful: 1) Using Wiktor's proposed `regmatches` and setting the `invert` argument to `TRUE` will remove the matches. 2) Another addition to Wiktor's pattern may be useful. In my case, I also want to ignore the parentheses inside the curly brackets when the parentheses are preceded with certain words (and no spaces in between), such as `first`, `last`, and so on. Then a negative look-behind `(?<!first|last)` can be useful, such as: 
`(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^{}]*?\K(?<!first|last)\([^()]*\)(?=[^{}]*})`.